# Old video adapters cannot to play more than 30 frames per second videos

Tags: drivers, graphics, video

I use Ubuntu-Studio 20.04.3 LTS inside two desktop computers and one laptop computer.

That laptop is a HP 250 G5 device, which we can consider as an old computer.

The internal video adapter of that laptop isn't capable to play UHD videos with more than 30 frames per second.

I tested it with the same video, same resolution, same format file, but 29.97 fps and 50 fps. The 29.97 fps version is played "satisfactorily". I mean, we can see it (some stuttering, but not to ugly). The 50 fps version... Not comment. Simply: TOO BAD!

Of course, the right solution is to get a new device.

But... I wonder if there is some way to work around this, in the old device.

Some idea? ???

Here is the output of `lscpu`

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  4
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-6006U CPU @ 2.00GHz
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               78
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  2
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            3
    CPU max MHz:         2000.0000
    CPU min MHz:         400.0000
    BogoMIPS:            4001.60
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse
                          sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl 
                         xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma
                          cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand l
                         ahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flex
                         priority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clf
                         lushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp
                         _epp md_clear flush_l1d
Virtualization features: 
  Virtualization:        VT-x
Caches (sum of all):     
  L1d:                   64 KiB (2 instances)
  L1i:                   64 KiB (2 instances)
  L2:                    512 KiB (2 instances)
  L3:                    3 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:                    
  NUMA node(s):          1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
Vulnerabilities:         
  Itlb multihit:         KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
  L1tf:                  Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cache flushes, SMT vulnerable
  Mds:                   Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Meltdown:              Mitigation; PTI
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Full generic retpoline, IBPB conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP conditional, RSB filling
  Srbds:                 Mitigation; Microcode
  Tsx async abort:       Not affected
```

Comment: Is this video formatted as H265? I have a HP 250 G6, which does not have the capabilities to decode H265 using the onboard Intel graphics. As a result, it tries to decode with software, and it becomes laggy. There is nothing you can do about it. I don't know if buying a dedicated graphics card would help. One workaround is to convert the videos to H264 format using Handbrake or a similar software. These laptops support hardware acceleration for H264 format.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I'll try to convert the video to H264. Stay in tune.

Comment: I don't have an HP 250 G6 but adding the output of `lscpu` to your question would certainly be useful. I know the Sandybridge line of CPUs does have the capability that @ArchismanPanigrahi mentions.

Comment: I just realized that I actually have a 250 G5 (same model as OP, not a G6), and added the output of `lscpu`.

Comment: I just can add that I think it is the webm format. I tried with H264 and it is the same result. But, when I converted the original file to m4v, with the same original resolution (3840x2160) and the same rate of frames per seconds (59.94)... Everything is fine, now! Now, I can see the video, without problems. So... There ise something about the webm format and this device. I don't have any clue about it.